# My getopt.h Code jumps in default-case after being in different case

Tags: c, linux, getopt

I want to add arguments to a program I have written, so I have made a couple of new project to learn and understand getopt.h library.

But for some reason if I run the program (`./parameter_test2 -n 21` or `./parameter_test2 --num 21`) it uses the right option and then jumps into the default case.
I have no clue why my code does this. Going from what I have read of, the default-case gets only called if there is an unknown return code.

Maybe one of you can explain to me what is happening.

CODE:

```
#include <getopt.h> /* getopt */
#include <stdlib.h> /* exit   */
#include <stdio.h>  /* printf */

void print_usage(char **argv)
{
  printf("+-----------------------------------------------------+\n");
  printf("Usage: \n\t%s [arg] [arg] [arg] ...\n",argv[0]);
  printf("\n");
  printf("\tProgramname --sender --Path /home/pi/Datei.txt\n");
  printf("\tTransceiver –s home/pi1/datei.txt\n");
  printf("\tTransceiver –r home/pi2/\n");
  printf("\n");
  printf("\t\tTransceiver [-s] SOURCE-PATH\n");

  printf("\t\tTransceiver [-r] [DESTINATION-PATH]\n");
  printf("+-----------------------------------------------------+\n");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  
  // if no parameters are given
  if (argc == 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "\nYou need to use options!\n\n");
    //printf("You need to use options!\n");
    
    print_usage(argv);
    }

  int next_option;

  const char *short_options ="-hn:";
    //  {"sender",        no_argument,       &f_sender,       1},
    //   {"receiver",      no_argument,       &f_receiver,     1},
    //   {"source",        required_argument, &f_source,       1},
    //   {"destination",   required_argument, NULL,  0},
    //   //{"verbose",

  const struct option long_options[] = {
    //{ name,   has_arg,            flag,  val}, 
      { "help", no_argument,        NULL, 'h' },
      { "num",  required_argument,  NULL, 'n' },
      { NULL,   0,                  NULL,  0  }
      };

  do {
      next_option = getopt_long(argc, argv, short_options, long_options, NULL);

      switch(next_option) {
          case '?':
              fprintf(stderr, "\nERROR: WRONG USAGE!\n\n");
              //print_usage(argv);
              //exit(2);
              break;

          case 'h':
              print_usage(argv);
              break;

          case 'n':
              printf("num %s\n", optarg);
              break;

          default:
              print_usage(argv);
              exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }   
  } while(next_option != -1);/* end of list */

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Runing the Programm:

```
./parameter_test2 -n 21                                                                     
num 21
+-----------------------------------------------------+
Usage: 
        ./parameter_test2 [arg] [arg] [arg] ...

        Programname --sender --Path /home/pi/Datei.txt
        Transceiver –s home/pi1/datei.txt
        Transceiver –r home/pi2/

                Transceiver [-s] SOURCE-PATH
                Transceiver [-r] [DESTINATION-PATH]
+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Well, you can execute your loop in your head. If `next_option` is `n`, it will execute it's case. And will try to read the next option, *in the next iteration*. But it will be `-1` if `n` was the last. So it will execute the default case.

Comment: You should move the call of `get_long_opt` before the loop and insert a copy after your `switch` before the end of the loop.

Comment: Another option is to add `case -1: break;` to the `switch` so it's not included in the `default:` case.

Comment: `do ... while` is almost always a mistake. Use `while ((next_option = getopt_long(...)) != -1) { ... }` then check that all required arguments are provided.

Comment: I fixed it by ```while(1){if(next_option == -1) break; /* end of list */...Code...}``` and by removing my "do ... while" loop. Thank you all for pointing my to my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was I should have checked `next_option` at the head of the loop.

I fixed it with:
`while(1){if(next_option == -1) break; /* end of list */...Code...}`
and by removing my `do ... while` loop.

**Here is my now fully working Code:**

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* exit   */
#include <stdio.h>  /* printf */

void print_usage(char **argv)
{
  printf("+-----------------------------------------------------+\n");
  printf("Usage: \n\t%s [arg] [arg] [arg] ...\n",argv[0]);
  printf("\n");
  printf("\tProgramname --sender --Path /home/pi/Datei.txt\n");
  printf("\tTransceiver –s home/pi1/datei.txt\n");
  printf("\tTransceiver –r home/pi2/\n");
  printf("\n");
  printf("\t\tTransceiver [-s] SOURCE-PATH\n");
  printf("\t\tTransceiver [-r] [DESTINATION-PATH]\n");
  printf("+-----------------------------------------------------+\n");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  
  // if no parameters are given
  if (argc == 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "\nYou need to use options!\n\n");
    print_usage(argv);
    }
  
  while(1)
  {
    const char *short_options ="-hn:";
    const struct option long_options[] = {
      //{ name,   has_arg,            flag,  val}, 
        { "help", no_argument,        NULL, 'h' },
        { "num",  required_argument,  NULL, 'n' },
        { NULL,   0,                  NULL,  0  }
        };

        int next_option = getopt_long(argc, argv, short_options, long_options, NULL);
        if(next_option == -1) {break;} /* end of list */

        switch(next_option) {
            case '?':
                fprintf(stderr, "\nERROR: WRONG USAGE!\n\n");
                break;

            case 'h':
                print_usage(argv);
                break;

            case 'n':
                printf("num %s\n", optarg);
                break;

            default:
                print_usage(argv);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
  }   
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

***Thank you all for pointing my to my mistake.***